# Adding a new virtual host / Directory for Vagrant Press [Wordpress on Vagrant]

Tags: apache, vagrant

I just brought up a vagrant virtual machine that is pointing to /vagrant/wordpress which is accessed by `http://localhost:8080`  , I would like to add one more folder which has already been shared by the host to vagrant and is mounted at /code , How do I edit apache to access this /code ?

praveen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your Vagrant setup, but IMO this should be handled by your provisioner (I'm using puppet).
Maybe you want to have a look at https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apache if i understand your question correctly.

Comment: basically now when I type the http://localhost:8080 on host machine , it is pointing to /vagrant/wordpress on the vm , I want to add another folder /code on vm to be accessed through http://localhost:8080/code , how do i do that?

Comment: but localhost:8080 should still point to /vagrant/wordpress ?
Then you could add a symlink in /vagrant/wordpress/code to your /code directory

Comment: `cd /vagrant/wordpress`
`ln -s /path/to/code code`

This should also be done by provisioning btw ;)